# Jquery divide table cell

Tags: javascript, module, division, calculation

I have a table with a couple of cells. When i click (with jquery) on a cell its get divided into four pieces (time interval, where every piece stands for 15 min).

```
// example
<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
         <div class="divider">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is working fine, but i want to calculate the width for every label (4 pieces). The width of the cell is changing when the screen gets rezised

For instance if the clicked cell has a width of 17 px.
I want to following width

```
// span 1: 4px    
// span 2: 5px    
// span 3: 4px    
// span 4: 4px 
// total: 17px
```

But if a cell has a width of 22px, the following result is disired

```
// span 1: 6px    
// span 2: 5px    
// span 3: 6px    
// span 4: 5px 
// total: 22px
```

I've tried several calculation with mod and dividing but could not get the disired result.

@edit | added JSFiddle code
In this file the td width is static set to 22px.
https://jsfiddle.net/cymvfmmb/

Comment: Share fiddle full code so that we can help better.

Comment: I've added a fiddle example code

Comment: use jquery resize event to calculate cell width at runtime.

Comment: I only need the calculation described above on how to divid the cell

Comment: I got it. why you need that ?? any internal calculations or styling process.

Comment: I need it for a timeline where on cell is one hour and I want that one hour is spit into 4 pieces every piece is 15 min

Comment: I don't think we need those values for this purpose. We can simply do it in CSS.

Comment: In css? Where the result is 6,5,6,5 px width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132133/discussion-between-sarath-kumar-and-bham).

Answer (score 0):

Calculation for divide a cell based on the width in to 4 equally or more related.

```
var n=25;
var length=n;
var arr=[0,0,0,0];

for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
 for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
  if(n){
    arr[j]+=1;
    n=n-1;
  }
 }

}
console.log(arr); //[7, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: It's working, Only the order needs to be different. The firsttime it needs to grep te smalest. Then it needs to check the biggest, smallest and biggest. So [7,6,6,6] Needs to be [6,7,6,6]

Answer (score 0):

How could i create a custom sort where

```
// Algorithm needs to be
// low | highest | lowest | highest
[7,6,6,6] would become [6,7,6,6]

// custom sorting the array
    arr.sort(function(x, y){
        if(y < x){
            return x - y;
        }
    });
```